# Syntax of ** in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, parameters, foundation, nserror

Simple question.  What is the meaning of the double asterisk in the interface below?  It's not an NSError pointer, but what?

```
- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pointer to a pointer to an `NSError`. It's used as an "out parameter" -- or you may want to think of it as a pointer to an `NSError` instance, considering an `NSObject` instance is always a pointer.

You use it like this:

```
NSError * outError = nil; << reserve place and a name for the out parameter

// pass the error so the client may return it to you:
BOOL ret  = [obj checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&outError]; 

if (nil != outError) { << the error was set in checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", outError); << log it
}
…
```

On the implementation side, it looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError**)outError
{
  if (self.isThingReachable) {
    // okay - the caller may not be interested in the error, test it:
    if (0 != outError) {
      // they are interested this time!
      *outError = [NSError errorWithBlahBlahBlah];
    }
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call it by sending a reference to an `NSError*`, like so:

```
NSError *myError = NULL;
[foo checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&myError];
if (myError) {
    /* look through info, handle error, etc. */
}
```

The `-checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` method can modify the pointer `myError`, including allocating space for a new `NSError`. This allows you to easily check if there was an error, by simply checking if `myError` is non-`NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post: ["Using NSError To Great Effect"](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/04/cocoa-tutorial-using-nserror-to-great-effect/) and pay particular attention to the section "Passing Pointers to Pointers."

Also the wiki page on pointers has a section on ["Multiple Indirection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Multiple_indirection)